# What function space does holomorphic functional calculus give us?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, banach-algebras, analytic-functions

Let $A$ be a unital Banach algebra, $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, and $A_U:=\{x\in A:\sigma(x)\subset U\}$. Holomorphic functional calculus says that any holomorphic function $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ gives rise to a function $\tilde f:A_U\rightarrow A$ satisfying certain properties. Now what can be said about the *space* of functions $A_U\rightarrow A$ that this generates? I.e. what is the set $\{\tilde f:f\in H(U)\}$?

My reason for asking is that I've defined an operation on functions $\tilde f$ given by $f\in H(U)$, and I'd like to extend the definition as far as possible. So I'd particularly like to know if $\{\tilde f:f\in H(U)\}$ is dense in some space of 'nice' functions $A_U\rightarrow A$. And I'd be interested in an answer even just for the case $U=\mathbb{C}$.

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: What is $\sigma$ in the definition of $A_U$?

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier Spectrum of $x$ relative to $A$, I assume

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier - Yes, spectrum of x in A. Sorry - I thought this was standard notation!